# utilizing django auth for website and applicative usage

Tags: django

I have an application that will be used in the field for data collection, sending data to a central server running django.  The user will be created on a website first, and then they will make submissions to that entry.  However, I will protect the field application with a UUID to be sure the app only gets run on one machine.

The question is, would it be considered 'safe' to extend the django User table (used for auth) to include this UUID field?  Or, is there a better way to handle two system authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the User table is only safe if you write your own authentication backend. Otherwise use [user profiles](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) for this purpose.